# AngularJS2 NodeJS ExpressJS refresh returns JSON results without HTML

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using angularjs2 with the lite-server and nodejs with express, when i am running my express server on port 3000, and navigate to that in the browser i get the HTML on the DOM as expected, but when i would navigate to a different path eg. localhost:3000/my_route, and maybe refresh later, i receive the expected response from the server but i do not get the HTML.This is how i configure express to get the index.html in the client side

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
```

I am using systemjs as module for angularjs2, can you guys please assist me with the appropriate setup, for nodejs/expressjs and angularjs2.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `/client`?

Comment: I just did but still

Comment: You might want to check the documentation site for express and angular2: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2/26878/getting-started-with-angular-2-with-node-js-expressjs-backend-http-example-incl#t=201702262028466991781

Comment: Thank you @echonax